# Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found

Tags: solr

I am trying to configure Solr for Sitecore 8.2. Solr is running and I have cores set up for each index and secondary cores set up for rebuilding. I'm not using the Solr support package.

I am getting the following error when trying to browse the site:

> Could not create instance of type: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex`. No matching constructor was found.

I'm guessing, it's a configuration problem. However, I can't get to `showconfig.aspx` to see what the issue might be.

Below is the patch config for the indexes:

```xml
<indexes>
  <index id="sitecore_core_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_core</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_core_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_master</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_master_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_web</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_web_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_marketing_asset_master</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_marketing_asset_master_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_marketing_asset_web</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_marketing_asset_web_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_testing_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_testing</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_testing_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_suggested_test_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_suggested_test</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_suggested_test_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_fxm_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_fxm_master</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_fxm_master_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_fxm_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_fxm_web</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_fxm_web_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="sitecore_list_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_list</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_list_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="social_messages_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_social_messages_master</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_social_messages_master_2</param>
  </index>
  <index id="social_messages_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_social_messages_web</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_social_messages_web_2</param>
  </index>
</indexes>
```

Comment: Thanks to all.
I have tried the below configuration to rebuild my index. No errors .It worked as expected.
Please remove the Patch after and refer my configuration in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out there were 2 issues I was having:

1. Because I was customizing the core names I needed to include a node for `sitecore_analytics_index`. Based on [this](http://sitecoreblog.patrickperrone.com/2015/03/on-secondary-thought.html) blog post I had left the node out thinking it wasn't needed.
2. Patch config order. My include file was getting patched too soon so the correct core names were not getting used.

Comment: Fixing the patch config order fixed it for me.  <param desc="rebuildcore" patch:after="param[@desc='core']">$(id)_rebuild</param>

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same issue as you and for me it was a really small change to the patching that fixed it:

Instead of:

```
<index id="sitecore_core_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_core</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_core_2</param>
</index>
```

Do this:

```
<index id="sitecore_core_index">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    <param desc="core">SitecoreSandbox_core</param>
    <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">SitecoreSandbox_core_2</param>
</index>
```

notice that in the first line `<index id=.....` I removed the `type` attribute. Its a strange thing, but that fixed it when I tried.

Comment: that's weird, the config in question works fine for me in 8.1 and 8.2 with or without the "type".

Comment: unfortunately that did not fix it. I must have something else going on.