# Enabling "Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild" Gives error

Tags: solr, patch-configuration

I am using `Solr Cloud` with `Sitecore 10.1`. When I enable the configuration file `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild` it gives me the below error.

[image]

Here is the text error message

Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: sitecore_core_indexsitecore_core_indexMainAliassitecore_core_indexRebuildAliassitecore_core_indexsitecore_core_index_rebuildSitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDatabasePropertyStoresitecore_core_index_rebuild

Please update if you have faced this issue.

Comment: Stack Traces/Error messages need to be in plain text, always.

Comment: See?  As soon as you provide the message in plain text, the site can actually find questions that match. Try searching next time perhaps :-)   https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/277/sitecore-contentsearch-solrprovider-switchonrebuildsolrsearchindex-no-matching?rq=1

Comment: The answer in the above link didn't help as I am using the default Sitecore Configuration. I haven't changed anything.